# I tried to create an extern object and store it in a pointer, resulting in 0x0

Tags: c++, pointers

It's a small qt projects.

In GameTimer.hpp

```
extern GameTimer *game_timer;
```

In GameTimer.cpp

```
GameTimer *game_timer = new GameTimer;
```

The class GameTimer has a method

```
long GameTimer::GetTime()
{
    return this -> total_time;
}
```

When I debug this project, I found that when I call `game_timer -> GetTime()` in other files of the project, the Debug program displays the value of game_timer as `0x0`. It looks like the program found the definition of this variable, but it's not correct.
Then I Change the method to

```
long GameTimer::GetTime()
{
    return 1;
}
```

and then the program ran successfully. I output the value of `game_timer` in the subsequent code of the program and the result looks fine.
I don't know why this pointer `game_timer` started at 0x0 and then went back to normal. This looks to me like the creation of this variable has been delayed. I've been debugging for a long time, but I still haven't found a solution

Comment: Sounds like you might have run into the Static Initialization Order Fiasco. https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order

Comment: After thinking about it, I think the problem is the Static Initialization Order Fiasco as aschepler said. The program has another extern variable and `game_timer` is called on its initialization.